# How to show an alert when a variable is changed?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to display an alert when a value is changed:

```
if(myVal == true) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

This should be executed everytime `myVal` changes. How to achieve this?

Comment: is myVal scope variable

Comment: `myVal` is `ng-model` on `input` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use $watch**

```
$watch('myVal', function() {
    if($scope.myVal == true) {
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
});
```

refer doc [AngularJS](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a [**watcher**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on `myVal`:

```
$watch('myVal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if($scope.myVal == true) {
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
});
```

---

*Note that `myVal` should be a variable of the scope.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watch` only when change like

```
$scope.$watch('myVal', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue != oldValue) {
        var value = newValue ? 'yes' : 'no';
        alert(value);
    }
});
```